# Spacing changes when using xaringan with ninjutsu and going from a list with one bullet point to two bullet points

Tags: r-markdown, xaringan

I am trying to create a complex incremental slide in Rmarkdown using the `xaringan` with `ninjutsu` for column formatting. I cannot (to my knowledge) use the standard approaches to incremental slides as elements are changing in multiple places (e.g., more text on the left hand column and an image that changes in the right hand column). Instead, I am recreating the entire slide each time. The problem I am having is that bullet lists change formatting as I go from one bullet point to two (even if I do not have multiple columns). Specifically, the spacing from text to bullets increases when I add a bullet point.

A simple document to reproduce the problem is:

```
---
title: "Test of bullet alignment"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    css: ["default", "ninjutsu"]
---

- A test

---

- A test

- B test
```

After knitting this document, when you go from the 1st to the 2nd slide the spacing from the bullet point to the text changes. This causes a noticeable change in the word wrapping that makes the slide look non-incremental.

Does anyone understand what is going on and have a solution or workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have such inconsistent space because you are adding extra space between two bullet points, which leads to wrap the texts `A test` and `B test` with paragraph html element `p` and `ninjutsu.css` contains the following line for styling the paragraph element.

```css
.content > h1, h2, h3, p { padding-left: 2%;padding-right: 2%; }
```

So when you are writing a single bullet point, that is not getting wrapped with `p` but in the next slide when you are writing two bullet points with an extra space between them they are getting wrapped with `p` and therefore, getting 2% left and right padding. And hence the problem.

But in default xaringan (in `default.css`) there's no such style rule for paragraph elements in slide content class. That's why, in the base case, there's no such space inconsistency.

### **Solution**

Now a possible solution could be to overwrite the css rule for `p` elements inside the list elements `li` and write your own rule for the desired padding (vertical and horizontal), which will work for both the below cases,

```
- A test

- B test
```

Or

```
- A test
- B test
```

**Rmarkdown file**

````
---
title: "Test of bullet alignment"
output:
    xaringan::moon_reader:
      css: ["default", "ninjutsu"]
---


```{css, echo=FALSE}
li p {
display: inline !important;
padding: 0px !important;
}

li {
padding: 6px 3px;
}
```

### This is non tight list (with  space between items)

- A test

---

###This is non tight list (with  space between items)

- A test

- B test

---

### This is tight list (with  no space between items)

- A test

---

### This is tight list (with  no space between items)

- A test
- B test
````

Comment: I believe you are talking about spacing in the vertical sense, whereas I am talking about spacing in the horizontal sense (i.e., from the bullet point to the text, not from one bullet point to the next bullet point). Perhaps I am mistaken, but I do not think your response addresses my question.

Comment: I don't have my laptop in hand which is why I can't check it, but presuming that you are talking about horizontal spacing, then does this mean that single bullet points are always treated as tight lists? Why does this affect ninjutsu but not base xaringan?

Comment: No, I am talking about inconsistent horizontal space from bullet to text from one incremental slide to next, which I believe is the problem you are facing. Did you try running the above code I have given here?! (Sorry If I'm still misunderstanding the problem here)

Comment: Sorry, for the misinformation ***this is not a xaringan issue***. See my updated answer. I have added some explanation. I completely focused on the solution and overlooked the fact `ninjutsu` may have something in it. Hopefully, I have made this clear now.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. However, this means that one always has to use tight lists as the padding will make normal, non-tight lists (i.e., with the spacing between lines in the Rmd file) way too spaced out in both horizontal and vertical. Non-tight lists are useful as they both add some vertical spacing (which can be fixed with your CSS) and they make your Rmd files more readable. Is it possible to achieve the exact same horizontal spacing with tight and non-tight lists in ninjutsu while leaving the vertical spacing unchanged for both and horizontal spacing unchanged for non-tight lists?

Comment: I believe you are asking for the same look no matter whether you have used a tight list or non-tight, right? If so see my updated answer.

Comment: Awesome! Seems simple enough, but I never would have figures this out myself. Someday I will learn enough CSS to make ugly websites, but not today...